# .NET 7.0 - OData 8.0 versioning not show in swagger

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, odata

I added OData to my project and tested some scenarios. I got stuck on adding versioning to OData, but I eventually added it without any major issues. Now, I can call the endpoint with the version without any problems, but it's not showing up in Swagger.

```
var modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
modelBuilder.EntityType<Order>();
modelBuilder.EntitySet<Customer>("Customers");

builder.Services.AddControllers().AddOData(
options => options.Select().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Count().SetMaxTop(null).AddRouteComponents(
    "api/v{version:apiVersion}/",
    modelBuilder.GetEdmModel()));


builder.Services.AddApiVersioning(opt =>
{
    opt.DefaultApiVersion = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiVersion(1, 0);
    opt.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
    opt.ReportApiVersions = true;
    opt.ApiVersionReader = ApiVersionReader.Combine(new UrlSegmentApiVersionReader(),
                                                    new HeaderApiVersionReader("x-api-version"),
                                                    new MediaTypeApiVersionReader("x-api-version"));
});

builder.Services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(setup =>
{
    setup.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";
    setup.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
});
```

Controller

```
namespace Aimtec.DataIntegrator.WebApi.Controllers.v1
{
    [ApiVersion("1.0")]
    public class CustomersController : ODataController
    {
        private static Random random = new Random();
        private static List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>(
            Enumerable.Range(1, 3).Select(idx => new Customer
            {
                Id = idx,
                Name = $"Customer {idx}",
                Orders = new List<Order>(
                    Enumerable.Range(1, 2).Select(dx => new Order
                    {
                        Id = (idx - 1) * 2 + dx,
                        Amount = random.Next(1, 9) * 10
                    }))
            }));

        [EnableQuery]
        public ActionResult Get()
        {
            return Ok(customers);
        }
    }
}
```

OData routing debug
[image]

Swagger
[image]

Also, do you happen to have a good guide on how to add versioning for OData in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Swagger's problem with controller matching. The easiest way is to add the `[ApiController]` attribute to the controller:

```
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class CustomersController : ODataController
{
}
```

It is worth noting that attribute routing is required after adding this attribute, which can be added to the controller or action.

About adding versioning for OData, you can check Sam Xu's article: [API versioning extension with ASP.NET Core OData 8](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/api-versioning-extension-with-asp-net-core-odata-8/).

Comment: Aaa perfect im blind. Thank you very much